# How to get the address of erc-20 token contract from token instance

Tags: ethereum, solidity

i create instance of  IERC20 public token in some contract.

How can i get the same address of token contract from the instance?
token.this?
token.address?

Answer (score 6):

All contract objects can be casted as an address in Solidity:

```
const address myAddres = address(myContract);
```

However usually you do not need to do this, but you can pass the `IERC20` object as is between functions.